# Is VPC enabled lambda architecture can be any better?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, subnet

Our architecture is a FAAS approach, where our entire backend is on Lambdas. The persistence layer is a managed Cloud Mongo Cluster, so called [Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas). Lambdas in the VPC talk to mongo cluster using a peered VPC connection.

I need a **VPC enabled Lambda**, because Lambda talks to mongo cluster using the **VPC Peering** connection. I need a **NAT gateway** because resources inside Lambda has to talk with external internet resources. Here is my **VPC-Lambda-Mongo** architecture:[image: VPC-lambda-mongo-architecture]

So my questions are:

1. **Security and Safety** is very important, Do you suggest any better architecture than this? I would be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If Security and Safety is very important, why are you even thinking about making the subnet public? You can save few bucks, but any accidental opening of inbound ports in the security group is a risk.
- You can use a NAT instance instead of NAT gateway. And if your outbound traffic through NAT is sporadic then go for `t2.micro` NAT ($9/month) or `t2.nano` NAT ($5/month)
- Most important: Running your Lambdas in public subnet may not be PCI/SOC2 compliant
- I am not sure if Lambdas in public subnet can access internet directly. If it is possible, then what is the source IP for the outgoing packet?

Comment: Thank you @helloV for your comments. My bad, I totally forgot about this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html. Even though Lambda is placed in public subnet, it cannot access internet resources unless it has an NAT Gateway. Thank you for the compliance information and the **NAT instance** suggestion. Makes complete sense. I have changed the question. BTW, if you feel the present architecture can be improved, let me know

Comment: Lambdas in a public subnet cannot access the Internet directly. They don't get an IP address assigned to them. If you want a Lambda to have access to both the VPC and the Internet you have to run them in a private subnet with a NAT gateway (or instance).